# Put subscript text below text and align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subscripts

I am trying to put the subscript text `{m=1/3\\n=1.9-2}` below the text AF and then align the two lines at the "=" sign.  Can you assist me in accomplishing this task?

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
AF_{\substack{m=1/3\\n=1.9-2}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep the default `c`entre alignment of `\substack` and play around with `\hphantom`s and `math` over`lap`s (using [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)) or use a `l`eft-aligned `\subarray`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  AF_{\substack{m = 1 / 3 \\ n = 1.9 - 2}} \qquad
  AF_{\substack{
    m = \mathrlap{1 / 3}\hphantom{1.9 - 2} \\
    \hphantom{m}\mathllap{n} = 1.9 - 2
  }} \qquad
  AF_{\subarray{l}
    m = 1 / 3 \\
    \hphantom{m}\mathllap{n} = 1.9 - 2
  \endsubarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

If you wish to stack the subscript *under* `AF`, then you can use `\mathop{AF}_{<substack>}`.

[image]